# How to set function default parameter inside class?

Tags: php, parameters, default-value

How to set function default parameter inside class?

```
class tag_0_model {
  protected $response_message;

  public function __construct() {    
    $this->response_message = array(
      "debug_message" => $debug_message =array(),
      "error_message" => $error_message =array(),
      "success_message" => $success_message =array(),
      "warning_message" => $warning_message =array()
    );
  }

  // sure this is parse error , not work
  public function insert_ignore($response_message = $this->response_message, $data) {
    //
  }
```

I try to use like

```
class tag_0_controller {
  protected $response_message;

  public function __construct() {    
    $this->response_message = array(
      "debug_message" => $debug_message =array(),
      "error_message" => $error_message =array(),
      "success_message" => $success_message =array(),
      "warning_message" => $warning_message =array()
    );
  }

  public function method() {


    $data = ...;
    $this->tag_0_model->insert_ignore($data);


    // or  


    $response_message = $this->response_message;
    $data = ...;
    $this->tag_0_model->insert_ignore($response_message, $data);
  }
}
```

Comment: did you get any error? the question isn't clear.

Comment: edit and add the error.

Comment: the argument not can be an attribute of class, you have to set a variable like $response_message=array()

Comment: @miglio Thanks for reply, I tried make if response_message isset or not isset use default array , but as you see the response_message attribute is long if I write into parameter , hard to read, is there some way can do the something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ You can not put required parameters after optionnal parameters, your "insert_ignore" function definition should have a default value for "$data"

2/ You can not put your property as a default parameter vlaue. Default parameters must exist at compile time, so it has to be a constant or class constant, I suggest that you put a default value to "null" and replace it from inside your funtion:

```
public function insert_ignore($data = array(), $response_message = null)
{
    if( $response_message === null ) {
        $response_message = $this->response_message;
    }
    // ...
}

// Call this function by
$this->tag_0_model->insert_ignore($data);
```

**EDIT** Updated code

Comment: thanks for reply so I can use like $this->tag_0_model->insert_ignore($data);  just leave the first one response_message parameter empty?

Comment: It would be: $this->tag_0_model->insert_ignore(null, $data);
Or you may change the parameter orders:
public function insert_ignore($data = array(), $response_message = null)
And then call it using:
$this->tag_0_model->insert_ignore($data);

(I've updated my answer)